# Standard article.sty doesn't recognize the \address{} command

Tags: templates, article, addresses

When I write articles to journals, I always use an already given template where I can put relevant information about the authors such as the addresses and e-mails.

But, for the journal that I am writing a new article, I am advised to use the standard article.sty. I can't use the \address{} because latex returns me the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \address
```

my .tex file has the following contents:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\title{my title}
\author{Author1$^1$, Author2$^2$ and Author3$^1$} 
\address{$^1$ address1}
\address{$^2$ address2}
\address{e-mails}

\maketitle
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: tabular is the macro or is the package? where I can find it? thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The environment. Kurt is suggesting that you use `\begin{tabular}{}...\end{tabular}`. If you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), somebody can show you.

Answer (score 4):

The intended usage in `article` is to place address information after the author separated by `\\` and to separate individual authors with `\and`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\title{my title}
\author{Author1\\
address 1\\
email@somewhere
\and
Author2\\
address 2\\
email2@somewhere
\and
 Author3\\
address 3\\
email3@somewhere}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

[image]